# foregroundColor for Textfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, textfield, swift4

Dears,

I'm learning swift and I'm trying to color a textfield text, the issue now is that the color is not applied to the text. please find the code next:

```
     let textStyle:[String:Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont (name: "Impact", size: 50)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth.rawValue: 3.5
        ]
```

Thanks

Comment: From apple "Use this attribute to specify the color of the text during rendering. If you do not specify this attribute, the text is rendered in black." So you are setting a white color on a white color no ? Foregroundcolor seems to modify the text color, I suppose it's not what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Remove the `.rawValue`. Also `textStyle` should be of type `[NSAttributedStringKey:Any]` not `[String:Any]`

Comment: Do realize you can simply set the property of the `UITextField`? `myTextField.textColor = UIColor.black`

Comment: I have tried to change it directly with .textColor and its working but not when I add the stroke color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key appears to be the `.strokeWidth`... If you want stroke and fill, the stroke width needs to be a *negative* value.

Give this a try:

```
    let textStyle = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Impact", size: 50)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth: -3.5
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this...

```
myTextField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "text",
                         attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```